# How to remove notes and attachment from account object?

Tags: attachment

Is there a way to remove the notes and attachment related list from account object so it won't show in the related list section of accounts?

Comment: What do you mean? Delete the notes and attachments from the database?

Comment: @Apex N-u-b, if you don't want `Notes and attachments` on your Account object layout, then just edit your `Account Layout` and remove `Notes and attachments` from `Related List` option

Comment: Anyone know why this question got a -6 rating?

Comment: It's a genuine question and i don't see any reason of downvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the page layout editor to remove the related list.

Answer (score 1):

I have been on this list for a few years. There are those who either have too much time on their hand or need to feel important so they spend their time squabbling about whether the powers that be deem a question worthy or not. Thank the Almighty I have found trailhead where they do not have a button up their whozits and just answers questions as long as it's asked in earnest and politely. Yey trailhead. That is how I get answers. Boo to many of the moderators on SE. Thank you DavidSchach for saying something and upvoting.